# Set custom steps in Jquery ui pips

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider-pips

I'm stuck with jQuery ui pips [http://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/].

There is default behavior that we can set steps by number.For example if I add 10 then it will execute it by "0,10,20...". But here I want custom steps like "0,499,199,499..". Please help me here.

Comment: Hi Amin, I'd like to help but your question is a little vague. A "step" is a multiplication value, it can only be a single value. Are you saying you'd only like to display pips on the "0th", "199th" and "499th" values ?

Comment: Yes exact values and it can be custom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify an array with the values you'd like to display as labels.
The trick here is to use an empty array and only fill in the indexes you want to show.

```
var labels = [];
    labels[0] = "zero";
    labels[99] = 99;
    labels[199] = 199;
    // ....
```

Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating the code in practise; http://jsfiddle.net/d5boxc30/1/